# Caddy server and subdomain point to port not working

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, graphql, caddy

I am hosting my Apollo Graphql api on digital ocean centos 8.
I can call the api using http://ip:4000/graphql

So now I want to replace with ip to subdomain an point to digital ocean ip from cloudflare.

I called https://api.subdomain.com/graphql but give HTTP ERROR 502.

May I know what configuration is wrong in caddy server since my qraphql server is up and running correctly.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  data_api:
    container_name: mycontianer-data-api
    image: asia.gcr.io/projectid/myimage/data-api
    expose:
      - 4000
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://url
      ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: xx
      REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: xx
    networks:
      - gita

  db:
    container_name: mycontainer-db
    image: asia.gcr.io/projectid/myimage/db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/:/var/lib/mariadb/data
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
      MARIADB_DATABASE: mydb
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - gita

  # Run the caddy server        
  caddy:
      container_name: mycontainer-caddy-service
      image: caddy/caddy:2.4.6-alpine
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443" 
      volumes:            
        - $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
        - $PWD/site:/srv
        - caddy_data:/data
        - caddy_config:/config
volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config: 

networks:
  gita:
```

Caddyfile

```
# Replace example.com with your application's domain
api.mydomain.com {
  # node-app:4000 is the docker container running the Node.js application
  # in our case it's exposed on port 4000
  reverse_proxy data_api:4000  {
    header_down Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
  }
}
```

error log

```
{"level":"error","ts":1641130172.422903,"logger":"http.log.error","ms g":"dial tcp: lookup data_api on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host","request":{"remote_addr":"x.x.x.x:63678","proto":"HTTP/2.0","method":"GET","host":"api.mydomain.com","uri":"/graphql","headers":{"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":["?0"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"],"Accept-Language":["en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"],"Sec-Ch-Ua":["\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"96\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"96\""],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform":["\"macOS\""],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"]},"tls":{"resumed":false,"version":772,"cipher_suite":4865,"proto":"h2","proto_mutual":true,"server_name":"api.mydomain.com"}},"duration":0.008050226,"status":502,"err_id":"ez8m3vaqk","err_trace":"reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:886)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to chaange caddyfile as follow
Caddyfile

```
api.mydomain.com {
  reverse_proxy /graphql* {
    to mycontianer-data-api:4000
    header_down Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
  }
}
```